# sed, how to replace one line with 2 line?

Tags: regex, insert, replace, sed, debian

I am trying to replace 1 line with 2 lines using sed in Debian and here is what I came up with:

```sh
sed -i 's/You are good/You are good\n You are the best/g' /output.txt
```

However, when I do this, sed kept complaining saying "unknown option to `s`".

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is for a shell script and the environment is Debian 6

Comment: Just a general comment, I suggest using `#` instead of `/` for your delimiter character in sed, as a general rule.  Occasionally you'll want to use `/` as a delimiter in the case of editing a file or stream that contains `#`s (e.g. for the comments in a bashscript).  But more often (in my experience at least) you'll edit text with no `#`s, but with `/` as part of a Linux dir. listing.  If you use the pound sign you won't have to worry about delimiting (although other delimiting rules apply).  Here's a crude ex.: `echo '/a/' | sed -e 's#/a/#//#g'`  vs. `echo '/a/' | sed -e 's/\/a\//\/\//g'`

Comment: Kudos re the separator - I've been pushing this one for years - unfortunately every example of sed you ever see uses / as the delimiter - which is about the most unhelpful character to choose.  OK, given that you can use any char, 'e' might be worse - sed 'sesom\estring with an \ee/\el\ephantsee'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this if you're in bash:

```
sed -i.bak $'s/You are good/You are good\\\nYou are the best/g' /output.txt
```

Strange, eh? But seems to work. Maybe sed can't handle the newline correctly so it needs to be escaped with another backslash, thus `\\` which will become a single `\` before going to sed.

Also, note that you were not passing an extension to `-i`.

---

#### Edit

Just found another solution. As the newline needs to be escaped when passing to sed (otherwise it thinks it's a command terminator) you can actually use single quotes and a return, just insert the backslash before entering the newline.

```
$ echo test | sed 's/test/line\
> line'
line
line
```

Answer (score 19):

Or, instead of search and replace (`s` command), search and append (`a` command)

```
sed -i '/Your are good/a You are the best' filename
```

Comment: Hmmm that's neat, I didn't know about that sed functionality.  Handy!

Comment: how can I start the new line with spaces? say I'm editing an YAML file

Comment: @HVNSweeting `sed '/xx/a \ \ yy'` (for 2 spaces)

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:

Probably my favorite method at present is to use a special character in place of '\n'.  Quoting rules get to be such a headache when you're passing around a string.  But if you pack your string with, say `|` in place of `\n` and `_` in place of   then you have a truly portable representation you can pass to functions, etc.

Here's an example:

```
whatAmI=$( printf "Wow oh wow\nYou are good\n"| \
             sed -e 's#\(You are \)\(good\)#\1\2|\1the best#g' | \
             tr '\n' '|' | tr ' ' '_' )
```

Result:

> Wow_oh_wow|You_are_good|You_are_the_best|

To "unpack" your squashed string just pass it through the same `tr`, but with the order reversed.

i.e.

```
echo "$whatAmI" | tr '|' '\n' | tr '_' ' '
```

Result

> Wow oh wow
>   You are good
>   You are the best

---

In addition to the above strategies (using appen --`/a` and delimiting with `\\\n`) you can also do this:

```
sed -i 's/You are good/You are good'"\n"' You are the best/g' /output.txt
```

In a way I prefer Glenn Jackman's solution as it's truer to the intent.

But I find this strategy useful as you can also use it to pass in variables in bashscripts.  If you're not going to use a variable more than once, it's cleaner to do than `-v`, e.g.

```
whatYouAre="okay"
sed -i 's/You are good/You are good'"\n"' You are '"${whatYouAre}"'/g' /output.txt
```

(Note: single quotes also work for the `\n`, but not for passing in vars, as it requires interpretation.)